# How can I combine rows that have a matching column?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the following structure:

```
+----+------+------+----------------+---------------------+
| id | val1 | val2 |     email      |     lastUpdated     |
+----+------+------+----------------+---------------------+
|  1 |    0 |    3 | test@gmail.com | 2015-02-07 13:21:55 |
|  2 |    5 |    0 | test@gmail.com | 2015-02-07 09:12:27 |
+----+------+------+----------------+---------------------+
```

Due to an error in a query I made, there are multiple rows with the same "email" value. I would like to merge val1, val2, and lastUpdated (greater value) for all duplicates. It would give a result like this:

```
+----+------+------+----------------+---------------------+
| id | val1 | val2 |     email      |     lastUpdated     |
+----+------+------+----------------+---------------------+
|  1 |    5 |    3 | test@gmail.com | 2015-02-07 13:21:55 |
+----+------+------+----------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: Are you adding `val1` and `val2` or taking the `MAX` as in Petar's answer below?

Comment: val1 and val2 are actually guaranteed to be either 0/X or X/0 respectively due to what I had before. I want to replace the 0 with the X of the duplicate, then delete the duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that all the `valX` columns are all zero except for in one row,

```
RENAME TABLE originalTable TO messedUpTable
;
CREATE TABLE originalTable
SELECT
  id,
  SUM(val1) AS val1,
  SUM(val2) AS val2,
  email,
  MAX(lastUpdated) AS lastUpdated
FROM messedUpTable
GROUP BY email
;
-- check originalTable to be sure it is okay
;
DROP TABLE messedUpTable
```

If you had indices on `originalTable`, you'll have to define them again.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ee0ad/1) with index examples put in.

Comment: I ended up making some small modifications to protect against some bad rows, but this is what put me on the right path. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

```
select max(val1), max(val2), email, max(lastUpdated)
from your_table
group by email
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to select, I want to actually modify the table so that there is only one row for each email.

Comment: It's not clear what the id values should be. Can't you just insert the result of the select into a new table, delete the old one and rename the new one?

Comment: I was thinking about trying that, but I'm fairly inexperienced with database work, so I was hoping I could just fix it in one query. Guess I'll hash that solution out.

Comment: When I am not experinced in something I personally prefer to do it in small steps that I completely understand, rather in one big complicated step... But that might be personal preference :)

Comment: Note - `MAX` is not correct if the column can have negative values. (It doesn't in the example, but better safe than sorry.)

Comment: He said "greater value" in the statement of the problem

Comment: The scope of `(greater value)` is ambiguous ("val1, val2, and lastUpdated" or just "lastUpdated"). However, it makes sense for date (which is immediately before parentheses), whereas it does not make sense for the numeric columns.